# Why was my flag ("un-make this answer Community Wiki") refused?

Tags: discussion, moderation, community-wiki

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/193023/20774) was posted a few days ago. The OP decided to make it into a Community Wiki answer because they wanted to "[disown](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193022/what-would-the-effect-of-the-happily-ever-after-potion-have-been-on-fiona/193023#comment528971_193023)" it because they felt that their answer...

> "[isn't worth the votes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46266076#46266076)".

Since this isn't what the Community Wiki button is for (CW should only be used where there is an expectation of considerable community input) I flagged it for a moderator to un-Community Wiki it. My flag was refused

> *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*

---

- **Why was this flag refused?**
- **Bonus question. Does this mean I can now use the Community Wiki to avoid upvotes and downvotes on poor quality answers?**

Comment: Whilst I disagree that, that particular answer should be CW (and I believe others do too from a discussion in TREU) I have a feeling it was declined because "it's their answer to do with as they please". Either that or it's an awkward process (I don't know) to do and not worth the effort.

Comment: I didn't decline your flag, but I had to decline a similar flag from another user because, although I personally agree with you in principle, [apparently Stack Exchange doesn't](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/17) (link is to another site's meta, but an answer from a CM which appears to be network policy).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot given people's worries in TREU about "answers in comments are a way of gaming reputation as you can't be downvoted" so is a Community wiki answer. You can't post dubious answers of dubious quality and not be downvoted for it. That's dangerous.

Comment: @Randal'Thor TL;DR: What's the short version?

Comment: @Edlothiad FWIW, I had the feeling, from his messages in TREU, that SQB was more worried about _upvotes_ that downvotes in that case ([related chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46266076#46266076), by the way; it should be linked on this Meta page). Also, we have to define "dubious quality": while I'm not a big fan of the _we don't know_ answers, they're still relevant ones when they're argued and not sloppily written because 'duh, man'. Would you have another example/definition to provide wrt "dubious quality"? :)

Comment: @Jenayah - the answer in question seem very sloppy to me. If it had been someone other than SQB I'd probably just have downvoted and dropped it into the delete queue

Comment: Uninteresting for sure (as I said, not a big fan of the _we don't know_ ones, no offence SQB). On the other hand and FWIW, I feel this "dv and VTD if it wasn't for SQB" argument is wrong, both because 1/ it does provide an answer (albeit a dull one) 2/ what's that thing about SQB or anyone else? [To quote Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85359), _Focus on the content. Not the users. DV poor content, up-vote good content, flag abusive content..._ Of course, one's free to vote as they wish and won't get burned for it (I think?), but still, if you do think it was that bad, that feels wrong.

Comment: @Jenayah - I think the status of the user is relevant in this case. This isn't an infrequent or new user who's pressed the wrong button, it's a frequent poster who's executing a deliberate strategy to use the Community Wiki to evade up and downvotes. Will we now, for example, start to see these CW "*we don't know*" popping up all over the place?

Comment: There's no point downvoting here, as the rep punishment doesn't exist for the person who's posted the answer, only for the person downvoting. (This might not be true, the downvoter might not lose the usual 1 rep).

Comment: (1/2) I'm not saying SQB is your random passing-by hillbilly (far from it), I'm just quoting a policy which seemed contradictory with what you were saying. Coming back to the CW situation (because my comment above was a digression anyway), well, it _could_ be a CW if people were actually committed to adding info to it (interviews or stuff, I don't know); though honestly, on a very hypothetical Shrek question, that will likely never be the case (SQB's still the only user of that CW, I think). If it's not clear enough by now, I'm not a fan of that one being a CW, either.

Comment: (2/2) Would we see 'em pop up everywhere? If it's for rep purposes, unlikely, since it's been established that using CW for reputation denial mechanism is wrong. If it's one 'rogue' user sometimes 'donating' (per SQB's words in chat) their answer to the community, this seems debatable (what we're doing now), but not a threat of sorts.

Comment: @Jenayah why wait until we're riddled with ants instead of cleaning up the food now? Do we need to have a problem to fix a problem or can we prevent it before it happens?

Comment: @Edlothiad what I meant is that if the 'problem' is caused by one frequent, _reachable_ (on TREU or elsewhere) user, I _think_ it'd be more appropriate to discuss that with them there, and then post the relevant points on a Meta post of "why nobody should do that", rather than going lengths and lengths here (even if it's Meta). Or you know... We could just wait for SQB to log back in and see what's the main concerned has to say - honestly, I don't think we'll move way further without more info on his part... :)

Comment: @Jenayah - I don't see that his opinion is particularly relevant, beyond that of any other user. We know *why* he did it, the question is "was that an appropriate thing to do?".

Comment: What I meant is that, maybe (or maybe not, time will tell!) SQB willing to post a full-fletched answer which could expose the arguments he thinks are in favor of it being "an appropriate thing to do" (whether that be from him or anyone else). Once again, FWIW I don't think it was, but all parties should be heard! And an actual answer would be more relevant to the story than the couple of chat messages we're basing ourselves on at the moment, that's all :)

Comment: @Edlothiad Often it's a waste of time to worry about problems that don't exist yet. Maybe they never will exist. Effort is usually much better spent on addressing existing problems than trying to address things that may or may not become problems.

Comment: @Randal'Thor it’s a waste of time to fix a problem when we’re anyways discussing it? Surely that’s the best time to fix the problem, instead of spending time discussing it, doing nothing, then having to re-do all the work to then “fix” it then..?

Comment: @Edlothiad - It may not be worth upvoting or downvoting as punishment or reqard - but, it's still worth upvoting or downvoting as a useful (or poor) answer, for the sake of users coming to the question. (In principle, at least; as a quotidian answer to an odd question, as Jenayah notes, no one may care enough to vote either way). I'd like to think that punishment/reward is a secondary consideration, and indicating an answer is good or bad is primary; that's how I try to behave, at least.

Comment: @RDFozz my general logic is “if it’s below 0, it’s marked as a poor answer” there’s not much difference to a -3 CW answer and a -50. However, a user, instinctively, reacts when a bunch of red pops up removing their rep. (Bare in mind when I wrote those comments I was under the presumption downvoting a CW answer would still cost me 1 rep.)

Comment: @Edlothiad - Good point - past a certain point, one is unlikely to downvote an answer (though we don't apply the same standard when upvoting - but, upvoting doesn't cost *me* rep). Not that I won't downvote a -3 if it's a *really* bad answer, especially in less entertainment-oriented stacks (e.g., the DBA stack).

Comment: @RDFozz I do the same with upvotes, I think our site is quite bad with upvotes, and I think upvotes a reasonably poor measure of quality. I’ve seen some objectively _false_ answers get 50+ upvotes with the correct canon answer sat at 2.

Comment: "The intent of community wiki in answers is to help share the burden of solving a question. An incomplete “seed” answer is a stepping stone to a complete solution with help from others; an incomplete question is a hindrance and an obstacle to getting a solution as no one understands the inquiry." – [Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/) - Yeah... I've seen a 'real' CW like ten times in eight years (half are, *ID this pic*). It *is* the disown button. My emotional rep cap is about 50; you'd of learned this a long time ago if yours wasn't somewhere above 200.

Comment: Flagging a moderator isn't for making someone lay in a bed that they've made. You should just vie for deleting the bed, assuming its removal won't harm posterity.

Answer (score 10):

We don't un-wiki posts unless there's a very compelling reason to, and CW'ing to avoid *gaining* rep certainly doesn't fall into that category. Using CW to avoid rep loss on a post expected to net negative rep is really the only questionable use for it, and given current guidance (below) even that would not be reason to un-wiki the post(s). If someone developed a habit of doing so, they may well get a "consistently low-quality answers" mod message though.

[Shog9 gave a thorough discussion of CW and un-wiki-ing on another meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/982), as linked to in the comments:

> ### Summary
>
> If an author chooses to use Community Wiki, that's their business - the system has informed them of the consequences and they've made their decision. If you encounter one of those rare situations that demands a wiki answer, especially one where only a wiki answer is appropriate for a given question... Then raise a discussion and get the moderators involved. If you observe harassment, flag it. If you see a bad answer, downvote it; a good one, upvote it. And if you don't see a problem... Don't make one. Each day has sufficient problems as it is.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean I can now use the Community Wiki to avoid **upvotes and downvotes** on poor quality answers?

No.

CW does two things:

- Prevents you from gaining or losing rep.
- Lowers the rep requirement for editing.

Neither of those two things has anything whatsoever to do with how voting behaves.  CW answers can rise and fall like any other, get grayed out after being heavily downvoted, and can be deleted by the community where necessary.  They are not "special" and do not get any protection from the site's core functionality.

If an answer is low-effort, downvote it.  If it is CW, downvote it anyway.  CW is not an excuse for posting bad answers.

Maybe you meant this:

> Does this mean I can now use the Community Wiki to avoid **losing rep** on poor quality answers?

Yes, technically, but you should not be writing poor quality answers in the first place.  Poor quality answers should still be downvoted and delete-voted regardless of CW.  The problem in this case is *not* "A high-rep user used CW wrong."  The problem is "A high-rep user wrote a low-effort answer."  The solution to that problem is the downvote button (and in some cases, the delete button).  If you notice a pattern of low-effort answers from the same user, either take it to meta or flag it for moderator attention.

As the CMs often like to point out, a lot of energy is expended arguing over the merits of answers to poor questions.  That may be the case here.  This answer basically says "The question doesn't have an answer because it is too speculative."  That sounds a lot more like a close reason than an answer to me.  And when we scroll up, the question is closed as *Primarily Opinion Based* (it also has 4 reopen votes, so who knows what will happen next).  If a question does not have an answer, carefully think about whether it is closeable.  Not all questions with no answers should be closed, but many of them can and should be.  If you're confident that *this* question should not be closed, then your there's-no-answer answer does not need to be CW because it's a perfectly good answer (and, ideally, it cites specific sources where an answer could have been found but wasn't).

We should also note that downvotes are -2 a pop.  It takes hundreds of downvotes or more to make a small dent in the average high-rep user's total.  An answer can receive *five times* as many downvotes as upvotes, and still have no overall effect on the author's rep.  Answers need to be overwhelmingly downvoted before they start losing you rep in large enough quantities to matter.  Case in point: the linked answer has, at the time of writing, +1/-2 votes for a net rep gain of +4 (if it were not CW, that is).  Even without that upvote and with an extra downvote, it would only impose a penalty of -6 rep.  What difference would that make?

> Does this mean I can now use the Community Wiki to avoid **gaining rep** on poor quality answers?

Yes, but you probably *wouldn't* be gaining all that much rep from a poor quality answer without said answer being CW in the first place (see next part), so it's a bit of a moot point.

If you would have gotten a lot of upvotes even without checking the CW box, then maybe it isn't all that bad of an answer.

> Does this mean I can now use the Community Wiki to **encourage upvoting or discourage downvoting** on poor quality answers?

In theory, no.  In practice, maybe.

As I said above, people should vote the same on CW answers as they do on regular answers.  "The author won't get rep for this" is a terrible reason to upvote anything.  It has nothing to do with the quality of the content, and so it will not cause good content to rise to the top (which is [the whole point of voting](/tour) in the first place).

However, people have an annoying tendency to vote more leniently on CW answers than on non-CW answers.  This causes them to clutter up good questions and make them look like they have been addressed when in reality they still need a real answer.  My preferred solution to this problem is to actually write a real answer (or ask someone else to do so), and let it outscore the CW answer.  But this is often impractical for a variety of reasons.

I don't have any good solutions here, aside from consciously and deliberately changing our voting culture to stop favoring CWs.  In the short run, people with deletion votes should consider using them where appropriate, and the rest of us can make do with flags (again, where appropriate).  All of us could downvote these a bit more heavily.

> Does this mean I can now use the Community Wiki to avoid **rep notifications** on poor quality answers?

I suppose, but you do still get comment notifications, and downvoters can and should leave comments explaining their downvotes.  Rep notifications are not a particularly effective way of communicating with authors, so this is a Good Idea for any kind of answer, not just CWs.

(Anyway, there's always the nuclear option of contacting Stack Exhange and telling them to dissociate your name from an answer... that will stop you from getting any notifications *and* disown the post in a far more thorough way than CW does.  No amount of arguing on meta will take this loophole away, it's baked into section 4(a) of [the copyright license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode).)

Comment: I’m not sure how this answer is really relevant to this meta. It seems to take a pseudo pedantic point to make a point. It also makes some quite wrong statements about hardcoded policies we have on site.

Comment: @Edlothiad Actually this answer makes an excellent point, albeit perhaps at unnecessary length. It's important to remember that rep changes don't matter that much: the main purpose of voting is to **visibly mark a post as good or bad**, not to reward or punish a user. And CW doesn't stop us from using our votes to do that; the only thing it does is prevent the poster from gaining/losing rep when we use our votes for the purpose they were intended for.

Comment: The only thing I'd disagree with is "*people have an annoying tendency to vote more leniently on CW answers than on non-CW answers*". In fact, I'd say it's the other way round: people are more willing to downvote CW answers than non-CW answers, because downvotes on CW are free.

Comment: It makes _a_ good point, amongst various false ones. Such as when to VTC, VTD, amongst others.

Comment: @Randal'Thor If rep changes aren't all that relevant (which I absolutely agree with), then *avoiding* rep changes (no matter if *positive or negative*) isn't really a valid reason for CW either. Using CW to avoid positive rep gain is as much a symptom of too rep-minded a community as using it for avoiding downvotes. If rep doesn't matter, then why are you CWing?

Comment: @TARS You're right, but as a counterpoint: if rep doesn't matter, why *stop* people from CWing? Un-CWing a post is an action too. It's possible to *discourage* something (e.g. using CW to avoid rep changes) without requiring that mod action be taken to prevent it.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I wrote that *some* questions with no answers (not necessarily this one) should be closed, and that *some* very poor answers (not necessarily this one) should be deleted.  I would be very interested in reading the meta discussions where we decided against doing either of those things.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It might be, but such moderator action can serve to *emphasize* that discouragement. What's a "discouragement" worth if there's not *actually* a problem with doing something? Not acting on it just washes this out.

Answer (score -6):

I was on the fence about voting to delete the question because while not actually opinion based — it's not asking "what do you guys think should happen?" — it's almost certainly only answerable through speculation.

As "primarily speculative" is not a valid close reason, I answered with a basic "we don't know". I disowned that answer, since I felt I was acting as the system / community user and therefore didn't want it associated with my account. I've read and agree with [what Shog9 has written about CW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/13).

Since there is now another *accepted* answer while mine proved to be controversial because of its cw status, I've deleted mine.

Comment: I approve of your action in deleting the answer but I disagree with your decision to do it in the first place, hence my downvote.

Comment: I think an argument can be made that pure speculation almost always involves opinion. Speculation based solidly on the information we *do* have is a little different - opinion is still involved in most cases, but the evidence included would make such an answer not *primarily* opinion. So, I'd think that something that requires speculative answers, where there's little evidence to go on, could safely be closed as primarily opinion-based.